# Posting article on LinkedIn vs. on company blog

Tags: professionalism, career-development, websites, blogging

Writing has always been an under-developed hobby of mine, and I recently got interested in writing articles related to the type of work I do (ie. software industry, so that means Technical how-to articles).

This is happening due to personal interest and since I'm sure it wouldn't hurt my career prospects (although I'm not actively searching for a new job). I'm a fairly entry level employee, but I have reason to think that the company would be interested in posting this content on their blog.

I'm trying to decide if I should post it myself on LinkedIn, or post it through my company's blog (which gets featured heavily on LinkedIn).

1. From a career and professional perspective, what would be advantages and disadvantages to each publication method?
2. If I do it on my company's blog, do I need to be concerned that the company owns the content, rather than me? (In case I ever want to re-use it)
3. If I do it on my company's blog this time, is it unprofessional to choose *not* to use my company's blog for future articles?

Comment: Could you at least get your name attached to it if it is on your company's blog?

Comment: Will you be doing this on your own time or during working hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the writing is done during working hours, the content will almost certainly belong to the employer and will go to the company blog.

Assuming you'll be writing on your own time, where to post depends on very much specific to your situation. An exception would be if your employment contract is quite strict regarding outside-work activities. In some jurisdictions, employers may contractually own the entire creative output of an employee - even activities not related to the employee's function at work.

Posting on the company blog will probably do you good (or at least no harm) internally in the company, while having your own blog could contribute to you building/strengthening your personal brand. In my experience, most companies wouldn't really care either way - even though they obviously all would prefer you writing for them on your own time.

It's anyone's guess whether it could be an issue at your company, as it would depend on the general company culture, the actual content and your position within the hierarchy - in addition to whether your ambitions 100% lie within the company or you are taking a longer view career-wise. It's possible that an employer would view a private blog as a sign of not being 100% loyal. It's also possible that they would appreciate it, if the company is mentioned and the content reflects well on them.

The only real personal benefit I see in publishing your content on the company blog, would be if it has a much wider audience than you can ever hope to build.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to decide if I should post it myself on LinkedIn, or post
>   it through my company's blog

Do both.

Marketing yourself makes sense. Marketing yourself individually and through your company's heavily featured blog makes even more sense.

Be sure that your posts can stand on their own and don't reference company-specific information.